# CSS column-count splitting my table into two different columns

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout, column-count

I'm trying to create newspaper-like columns on my page. However, my page contains tables, and in IE, Chrome, Safari, and Opera, the table is being separated into two different columns;this is not the behavior that I want. Where there is a table, I would like to have it entirely within one column.  Here is some code:

```css
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 5px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 5px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="newspaper">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Table Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Row 4</td></tr>
  </table>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

An easy way to see the problem and fiddle with it is to use Chrome and go to http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-gap and paste over the code in their example with mine.  If you try Firefox you will see that the table stays entirely within the left column.

Comment: So, what do you want is your table on the left and paragraph on the right, right>

Comment: Yes, but the reason I am using column-count is because my page is dynamic, and I want it to always take up the minimum amount of vertical space.  There could be a paragraph above the table as well, and I don't know which will be longer, so I am using column-count to layout the page, but I don't want the table split into two different columns.

Comment: I'm sure with my answer. But you must have a lot of paragraph. It will work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `column-break-inside: avoid;` to your table:

```css
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 10px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 10px;
    border:dotted 1px #ccc;
}
.newspaper table {
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -o-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -ms-column-break-inside:avoid;
    column-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

```html
<div class="newspaper">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Table Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Table Row 4</td></tr>
  </table>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems to work if I slightly modify your suggestion and add .newspaper table{
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
-o-column-break-inside:avoid;
-ms-column-break-inside:avoid;
column-break-inside:avoid;
}  Want to modify your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Why must the table? What is the longest? The table or paragraph? But. As you wish..

Comment: I don't know in advance which will be longer, the stuff before or after the table.  There will be lots of tables and paragraphs on the page.  I don't care so much whether paragraphs are split between the columns.  It is the tables splitting that bothers me.  Thanks again!

Comment: FYI - After using the above, Chrome, Safari, Opera, and Firefox were working, but not IE.  I changed -ms-column-break-inside to break-inside, and now it's working in all five of those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on what you are trying to accomplish here...

If you don't want 2 columns just remove the css. http://plnkr.co/edit/UtvHv0V9cydAfnO4jFwH?p=preview

If you want the paragraph to be on the right then make the table float left. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/52ly416gGmtHhAZSyrC3?p=preview

```
table{
    float:left;
}

p{
    position:relative;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  I definitely need two columns because I want the content to take up less room on the page.  I don't know in advance whether I want the table on the left or on the right, because the page is dymanic, with lots of tables and text on it, and that is why I am using column-count to layout the page automatically like newspaper columns.  It works exactly how I want in firefox.  I was hoping I could add a style to the table that would keep it from splitting up, sort of like you can do with page-break-inside: avoid, in order to get it to work in all browsers.